# Site build in WordPress loads perfect for everyone but no PHP loads for the client?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a site build on WordPress. Everything looks perfect on all devices. I've tested against Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE8+, Android, etc. No problems.

The client pulls up the site on their machine and phone and it stripped of everything in the header and footer that loads via php (header.php and footer.php). Shortcodes load the content as expected. but there's no page styling.

I tested again even had outside users test on phones (and even a Chromebook on a Starbucks wifi), looks fine.

I had the client clear cache, nothing. His machine is on a company network but his phone isn't but they both have the same issue.

I have a staging and production site, both have the same result.

----- Edit -----

The `head` in `header.php` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"; dir="ltr" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

The client's page source shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```

notice that the `wp_head();` didn't output the CSS. `profile`, `pingback`, and `viewport` didn't render either.

Comment: Can't be related to PHP, I would imagine it must be CSS or even JS somehow.

Comment: Is it possible to share the link on their machine or it is private?

Comment: @WheatBeak - See the edit. It's more than the CSS and JS not loading. `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` pull those in but they don't run.

Comment: @NikiMihaylov I can't share the site directly for privacy/contract reasons (otherwise I would, trust me)

Comment: **It is not same page at all**, maybe the other is 404. Look even at charset `UTF` and `utf`. I would first check php info on his machine, second is WP setting for domain, maybe you need to install first WP on his machine and than transfer the template.

Comment: @skobaljic There's nothing to install on his machine regarding `php.ini` or `wp`. It's all on Media Temple VPS servers.

Comment: Guess it is not a problem to install clean WP from his cPanel, than just transfer your template.

Comment: It's got to be user error then, are you certain they're at the right address? I only ask because I have had customers complain for days and days thinking their site isn't working just to realize they were still looking at a proof jpeg.